# Linking with libcurl library on xcode with latest and greatest openssl dependency

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libcurl, fips

We have a C++ project that compiles on MAC (OSX 10.9) and we need to make it FIPS compliant. This means that the process should call the function fips_mode_set in the beginning of the run and use a new FIPS compliant openssl library (we use version 1.0.2k). Our project uses the openssl library and the libcurl library (which depends on the openssl library itself) and compiles with xcode (6.2).

The problem is that xcode links to a libcurl version that depends on an old version of openssl library (0.9.8). How Do I compile a version that uses libcurl library on one hand, but depends on a newer version of openssl library on the other hand?